# How to create public key and private key by cnf File?

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography, csr

I have a `.cnf` file that I want to create public and private keys and CSR using this file.

I have a sample code, but it does not fully use all the fields of the `.cnf` file!

```
private static void GenerateKeyPair(string commonName, string serialNumber, string organization, string organizationalUnit3, string organizationalUnit2, string organizationalUnit1, string country)
{
    CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters
            {
                KeyContainerName = $"{commonName}_{country}_{serialNumber}_KeyContainer",
                
                Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore
            };

    // Create RSACryptoServiceProvider with the specified key container
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParameters))
    {                
        // Export public key                
        // Remove XML tags
        publicKey = RemoveXmlTags(rsa.ToXmlString(false));

        // Export private key  
        // Remove XML tags
        PrivateKey = RemoveXmlTags(rsa.ToXmlString(true));
    }
}
```

Sample `.cnf` file:

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = dn
[dn]
CN = companyName [Stamp]
serialNumber = Economical number
O = Non-Governmental 
3.OU = companyName
2.OU = companyName
1.OU = companyName
C = IR
```

I expected to be able to create public and private keys, but I couldn't!

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code has nothing to do with that CNF file. As far as I know, the CNF file is only consumed by the openssl command-line tool. I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: The cnf file looks like you want to create a certificate. A public/private key pair is required for building/signing a certificate but it is not a certificate. Therefore what you are asking for is not feasible.